# binding angular scop as javascript parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I want to bind some dynamic values to my javascript function call..

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right" onclick="addToCart('{{i.item_name}}','{{i.price}}')">Add to Cart</button>
```

How can I bind `onclick="addToCart('{{i.item_name}}','{{i.price}}')"`

Error:

```
Error: [$compile:nodomevents]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angularjs use ng-click and not onclick

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right" ng-click="addToCart('{{i.item_name}}','{{i.price}}')">Add to Cart</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the `i` is from an `ng-repeat`? Below should do the trick.

`ng-click="addToCart(i.item_name, i.price)"`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

You can assign those dynamic values to data attribute and read data attribute within your javascript method.

```
function addToCart(e){
   console.log(e.target.dataset);
   //{itemName:'...', itemPrice:'...'}
}

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right" data-item-name="{{i.item_name}}" data-item-price="{{i.price}}" onclick="addToCart(event)">Add to Cart</button>
```

**Solution 2:**

Write a method in your controller and call your javascript method from there

```
 //javascript method
 function addToCart(itemName, itemPrice){
     //your logic here
 }

 //inside controller
 $scope.addToCart = function(item){
     //javascript method call
     addToCart(item.item_name, item.price);
 };

 //html
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right" ng-click="addToCart(i)">Add to Cart</button>
```